# How to access Journals from iCloud.com

Tags: ios, icloud, photos.app, mobile-iphoto

Is there a way to access Journals publish by iOS iPhoto, directly from icloud.com, without knowing the link already.

Currently I have to "share the link with a friend" before I can access it on icloud.com, even though I have already synced it to icloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly access your Journals from iCloud.com, no. However, if you publish a Journal you can choose "Add to Home Page" ([iPad](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3156) and [iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3276)), that way if you have multiple Journals a visitor can navigate to your "Home Page".

A visitor would still need the unique link for at least one Journal even with that option selected. Alas, there is no "icloud.com/*user*/" link one could visit directly.

I don't think it's designed to be a landing page. It's more to generate a unique link for sharing said Journal.